# PHP function to convert special characters to unicode(UTF-16)

Tags: php, function, unicode, utf-16, utf

Is there a PHP function that can take a string and convert any special characters to unicode. Similar to `htmlspecialchars()` or `UTF8_encode()`.

For example in the string: *"I think Bob's going too"*.

I would need the apostrophe or single right quote unicode in place of the apostrophe in *"Bob's"*. So then after conversion the string should read: *"I think Bob\u2019s going too"*.

I need this for use in a PHP script that prints into a javascript function.

Using `\` to escape or `&#39;` does not work, it stops the script from running. I am trying to use [Flowplayers Playist plugin](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html). The only way it seems I can have a string with special characters is if they are in unicode.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3Sc/1/) to play around with and see what I mean when I say it doesn't work. Just replace `\u2019` with `&#39;` or something similar and click to have the song play. The media player just goes black and doesn't play anything, whereas if you leave it with `\u2019` then it plays fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `json_encode()` is the function you are looking for here.

The following code:

```php
$string = "I think Bob’s going too";
print_r(json_encode($string));
```

will output:

```
"I think Bob\u2019s going too"
```

Comment: I tried that in a new file and it did not print that for me. It printed it exactly the way it appeared in the string, nothing changed. Do I need to mess with settings in the php.ini or something?

Comment: I "fixed" the quote you were using in your example. Try and copy/paste my string, you should have my result. We are not using the same character, yours is ASCII, mine is \u2019 (' != ’)

Comment: ah you're right. Do you know of a way I can ensure the correct characters are used for encoding? I'm taking these strings from a user input.

Comment: You may want to disallow some characters from the user input (using a regular expression), so if any unauthorized character are entered, you reject the input.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm fixing a broken search feature where the special characters are stored like this in a mySQL column so what the user types doesn't match